# Testing installation and deployment of RPM

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel

I am developing a RHEL RPM that should be installed across a fleet of hosts. This RPM has a few custom actions during and post-installation that I want to test. This means I want to test:

- RPM installation
- A few runtime scenarios of the package after installing (the package is started via systemd)

I thought of using a VM/QEMU to test this, but I think I am over-complicating things.

Is a simple docker container enough to test this? How can I test a systemd startup?